# impossible to make ubuntu go to sleep when battery is low

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery, aspire-one, low-power

I have a bit of a problem with my acer aspire one 725 (Ubuntu 16.04) when the battery gets low. At first, I get a message at 10% battery (as expected), and everything is working fine. When my battery gets below 3% or 5% (can't remember which one it is exactly), I am simply not able to put it to sleep, it instantly "awakes". Even when I close the lid, the fan and hard drive keep spinning, and the activity light stays on

Also the shutdown on critical battery level does not work, the screen just turns turns black, but it stays active until the point where I have to force the computer to turn off by holding the power-button.

Would there also be some terminal outputs that could be useful to solve this?

Comment: cannot put ubuntu to sleep on low battery either. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: No, not yet. I settled for now with manually shutting my system down when it gets below 5%